# It seems that the examples about Forward–backward_algorithm on wiki does not make sense when interpret to sunny rainy story.

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning

[In the Forward-backward algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward%E2%80%93backward_algorithm), this Transition probabilities:

$\mathbf {T} ={\begin{pmatrix}0.7&0.3\\0.3&0.7\end{pmatrix}}$

could be viewed as the probabilities of the weather at t+1, for instance, $T_{11}$ could be viewed as

> the weather has a 70% chance of staying the same

the emission probabilities

$\mathbf {B} ={\begin{pmatrix}0.9&0.1\\0.2&0.8\end{pmatrix}}$

could also be interpreted as

> 90% people use umbrella when it is rainy

in this context, what does following observations mean?

$\mathbf {O_{1}} ={\begin{pmatrix}0.9&0.0\\0.0&0.2\end{pmatrix}}~~\mathbf {O_{2}} ={\begin{pmatrix}0.9&0.0\\0.0&0.2\end{pmatrix}}~~\mathbf {O_{3}} ={\begin{pmatrix}0.1&0.0\\0.0&0.8\end{pmatrix}} ...$

Comment: Don't forget to include links or references, so people know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, $\mathbf T_{11}$ is the conditional probability that: *the weather stays in state 1* (when it is in state 1).   It is that we have $\mathbf T_{22}=\mathbf T_{11}$ which indicates that the event that *the weather stays the same* is independent of the current state of the weather.

---

The diagonal elements of $\mathbf O_j$ present the conditional probabilities for observing event $j$ given each system state. These events are given in the array, $\{$umbrella, umbrella, no-umbrella, umbrella, umbrella$\}$.

So $\mathbf O_1$ presents us with the conditional probability for observing an umbrella would be 0.9 when given a rainy day, and 0.2 when given a sunny day.